# Show that there is no simple group of order $3393$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

> Show that there is no simple group of order $3393$

The hint I was given was to look at Sylow $3$-subgroups. I know that $3393 = 3^2 \times 13 \times 29$ and that $G$ must contain a subgroup of order $3^2$, say $H$. But how can I proceed further with this. The proof I managed to come up with was this.

*Attempted Proof:* Let $G$ be a simple group of order $3393$. Sylow theory tells us that the number of Sylow $29$ subgroups of $G$, $n_{29}$ is either $1$ or $117$ and that the number of Sylow $13$ subgroups of $G$, $n_{13}$ is either $1$ or <s>260</s> $261$. Since $G$ is simple we must have $n_{13} = 261$ and $n_{29} = 117$.

Let $\operatorname{Syl}_{29}(G) = \{H_i \ | 1 \leq i \leq 117\}$, since $H_i \cap H_j \leq H_i$ for any $i \neq j$ we must have $H_i \cap H_j = \{1_G\}$, for otherwise we'd end up with $H_i \cap H_j$. This shows that we have at least $117 \times 28 = 3276$ elements of order $29$ in $G$. Applying the same reasoning to $\operatorname{Syl}_{13}(G)$ we see that $G$ must also contain $261 \times 12 = 3132$ elements of order $13$. Thus $|G| \geq 3132 + 3276 > 3393 = |G|$ a contradiction. $\square$

---

Are there any errors in my proof? If not, how can I use the hint to prove this?

Comment: Where do you get $260$? The numbers must be congruent to $1$ mod $p$ and divide the order of $G$, neither of which is true for that number. I guess you probably meant $261$.

Comment: @MattSamuel: $29\times 4 = 116$; but $260$ is indeed incorrect; it should be $261 = 9\times 29$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes you're right, it should be $261$

Comment: @Perturbative: It would have been nice of you, then, to edit the question and fix the mistake, and then note in your comment that it’s been fixed. Don’t force readers of the question to go through the comments to find corrections!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My apologies, I was going to do that but was busy at the time. Thank you for going out of your way to edit the question on my behalf, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\img}{\text{img}}$

This is a bit late, but for posterity: there is in fact a sneaky way to do it by looking at the number of Sylow 3-subgroups (source: Dummit & Foote page 203; hopefully I'm exegeting it correctly :) ).

Suppose towards contradiction that $G$ is simple and has order $3393=3^2\cdot 13\cdot 29$. Let $n_3$ denote the number of Sylow 3-subgroups. By Sylow's Theorem $n_3\equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $n_3|13\cdot 29$. If $n_3=1$, we get that that Sylow 3-subgroup is normal and therefore $G$ is not simple. So basically, it must be either 13 or 29, but only 13 is congruent to 1 mod 3, so $n_3=13$. Also by Sylow's Theorem there is some Sylow 3-subgroup whose normalizer $H$ has index 13 in $G$.

(Some details to fill in for justifying the following paragraph, but) we can make a homomorphism $\pi_H: G \rightarrow S_{13}$. (Essentially, the codomain is representing the set containing $13$ cosets of $H$, and each $g\in G$ sends a coset of $H$ to some coset of $H$, so each element $g$ corresponds to a certain permutation of the set of cosets). Now recalling that kernels of homomorphisms are normal subgroups, we consider $\ker(\pi_H)$.

If $\ker(\pi_H)$ were all of $G$, that would mean that $H$ is all of $G$, but it's not because $H$ has index 13. Since $G$ is simple, $\ker(\pi_H)$ must be the trivial group. By the First Isomorphism Theorem, $G/\ker(\pi_H)\cong \img(\pi_H)$. Since $\img(\pi_H)$ is a subgroup of $S_{13}$, we know by Lagrange's Theorem that $|\img(\pi_H)|$ divides $13!$, so $|G|$ divides 13!. However, 29 divides $|G|$ but is not a factor of $13!$. This is inconceivable and outrageous, a contradiction.